# Facebook Graph API - Pagination (Swift)

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination, cursor

I'm trying to fetch Facebook friends for my app in Swift and I get a JSON like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Karen Alafeadafcahh Schrockescu",
      "id": "101771987049940"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mark Alafefedijcba Warmansky",
      "id": "100225727206277"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUmlZARmxZAc24wU1lkaGVkUGQ0Y041NXVSVHZAuUWRkYjNRRDJSSklXQUN2Y0pBM0VveUNERzJTQ2gtUGxVZAG5mZAVJoVmhqOVVkdVp0ckVRZA2dZAamJwNFR3",
      "after": "QVFIUlJMbnJZAdEFJNUJ1ZAjdFbGZAjVk5DWFRoR2doOFg1ZAy1qN2RPaWkydTNxUFRGMGVReFctSm9NUjVoUkJnTXA3UG1PZA0QzY3lrVzlzZAlJ4ZA2pwSHhsWWJB"
    }
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 10
  }
}
```

But there are no `"previous"` or `"next"` fields to get the next page of friends (there should be 10 friends in the example above). Am I supposed to specify it in some way in the parameters of the GraphRequest? Or is there some way to use the given cursors?

Thanks